# while updating pom xml - PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, selenium, maven-plugin

issue recently occurred after reinstalling intellij and now there are issues like: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: do you have some repositories defined in your pom.xml ?

Comment: Yes, mainly maven clean, dependency plugins like below.

            '<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>'

Comment: the problem could be with the ssl certificate of one of your repositories. Can you list the one with https protocol ?

Comment: there are no certificates currently in Intellij and i have no access to download it from IE. is there any alternative to this ?

Comment: can you list the repositories ? do you have configured repos URLs on https protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates , and check the box "Accept non-trusted Certificates Automatically". That might solve your problem. 
Also check your jdk version. I had to change to 1.8.0_192 on my Intellij. I was trying to build a spring boot application.